# rspamd intermittently mark outgoing emails with HFILTER_HOSTNAME_UNKNOWN

Tags: postfix, rspamd

We use rspamd to scan our outgoing emails so we can know if there's something wrong with our mail setup.

Some of the email is sent through normal mailboxes, others through systems, for instance an issue tracking system and a billing system.

For the emails sent by our issue tracking and billing systems, everything is fine 85% of the time. But 1 in every 7 emails sent by these systems are marked by rspamd with HFILTER_HOSTNAME_UNKNOWN.

From what I could find, this is caused when the IP address used for sending doesn't have a PTR entry in the DNS zone. But all the IP addresses used have a PTR entry, and the PTR works since 85% of the emails are not marked.

I compared the emails with the HFILTER_HOSTNAME_UNKNOWN and those without, and they seem similar, almost identical in some cases. I haven't seen any significant differences in the rspamd logs and the postfix logs either.

Some people say it might be because the PTR answer is too slow, but I'm not sure how we can measure that. I thought about adding some configuration to the "hfilter" modules of rspamd to be more forgiving, but configuration of the module is painfully limited: https://rspamd.com/doc/modules/hfilter.html

And well, it's not just a local rspamd problem. The email sent which have HFILTER_HOSTNAME_UNKNOWN are often thrown out at the reception. Maybe it's rspamd adding some "X-Spam" headers which makes thing worse (I haven't checked yet). Or it could be the anti-spam tool at the reception see the same thing and mark our emails with their equivalent of HFILTER_HOSTNAME_UNKNOWN.

Do you know anything I could do to help diagnose this issue?

I saw that rspamd comes with a tool called `rspamadm` which can be used to simulate stuff, but I'm not familiar with it.

Edit:

In the /etc/rspamd/options.inc file, the dns configuration section uses the default values:

```
dns {
    timeout = 1s;
    sockets = 16;
    retransmits = 5;
}
```

There is an /etc/rspamd/local.d/options.inc file, but it doesn't change de dns configuration.

Postfix log doesn't show `unkwown[123.123.123.123]` but rather the expected `myserver.com[123.123.123.123]`

Rspamd is not installed on the same physical server as the server trying to send the emails (so it's not trying to work through localhost), so delays in communication are possible. We have our own reverse DNS servers.

Comment: Well, can you see a higher share of failures with specific sending addresses, or is it just spotty across all messages? If one particular network is indeed providing unusual PTR replies and you like to hear ideas on why that might be an issue for your server, consider linking [a public test result page like this example](https://dnsviz.net/d/8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa/responses/).

Comment: @anx : thanks for the insights! I've edited my post to answer some of the questions asked. Maybe our reverse DNS is sometimes slow to answer?